# How to implement indexOf in solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays

In javascript, can use indexOf to get the index of the value.

```
const array = [2, 5, 9];
const index = array.indexOf(5);
```

How to implement it in solidity? I'll get the value from another function, and I want to use that value to find the index in an array(_R2), then delete that value.

```
uint256[] internal _R2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to loop over the values to find the one you are searching for.

Something like this:

```
function indexOf(uint256[] memory arr, uint256 searchFor) private returns (uint256) {
  for (uint256 i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == searchFor) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1; // not found
}
```

Comment: I think the return must be an `int256` instead `uint256` because the negative signed number in case of not found ( -1 ) and `if (array[i] == searchFor)` must be `if (arr[i] == searchFor)`

Answer (score 1):

So, Lauri's answer was kind of correct, but *array* should be *arr* on line 3 and an unsigned int can never be -1 so I would rather revert on that line. Code should look like:

```
function indexOf(uint256[] memory arr, uint256 searchFor) private pure returns (uint256) {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == searchFor) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    revert("Not Found");
  }
```